# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (3, 7) site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please i need help fast...

Here is the **code**:

```
list_of_categories = categories +['Others']

print("Classification Report: \n Target: %s \n Labels: %s \n Classifier: %s:\n%s\n"
      % (target,list_of_categories,classifier, metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)))

df_report = pd.DataFrame(data=metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred),columns = list_of_categories)
df_report.index = [list_of_categories]
df_report
```

And then i have this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1679         blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]
   1680         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1681         raise construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (3, 7)
```

I don't understand it... please help me!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (3, 7)
```

The error refer to wrong data-frame size calling in a sense calling rows that do not exist.

Comment: Well, that's not an answer to the question.

Comment: yes, i agree @AbhyudayVaish